# How to make algorithm text smaller in springer template?

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

I am currently running into a problem with latex code. The picture below is the algorithm in IEEE template and Springer template. I want to make the text in the springer template smaller (only in algorithm) to make it look like in IEEE template. How can I do that?
Thanks.
[image: Algorithm in IEEE template]

[image: Algorithm in Springer template]

Comment: Why? Isn't the point of having a custom template to make sure authors abide by the “house style”, so to speak? Are you sure they'd want you to modify your text in that level of detail?

Comment: I just feel like when I put the algorithm in Springer template, it looks a little bit clumsy compared to the IEEE template

Comment: If you consider making such changes to an article you want to submit anywhere, there is a probability that they will remove your customizations prior to publication. You may not like the result.